Cannot call operator with argument. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected with request.security
I am facing issue when I want to get the current price of the index and add 2 strike above or 2 strike below options value in the table to show the user which Call or Put is active, depending on the current price.
indicator( title='Breakout Stock', overlay=true,max_labels_count = 500)
strike = 100
real_atm = int(( math.round ( close / strike ) ) * strike)
strk = real_atm - (strike * 2)
    strikep = "NSE:BANKNIFTY" + "24" + "07" + "31" + "C" + str.tostring(strk) 

[op_open,op_close,op_high,op_low,opPr_Low] = request.security(str.tostring(strikep),timeframe.period,[open,close,high,low,low[1]])   

I want to take the closing price of the symbol and show the user Call or Put option value on the chart by concatenating year, month, day and call or Put.
How can I achieve this?

any help will be appreciated, will assign a bounty as well

Include a minimally reproducible example in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I have updated the question and simplified it to be more clear.

The first parameter in the function request.security() is a simbol, for example, syminfo.tickerid.

Yes, it is a symbol, I will concatenate it with string to get the options strike price.

I can only repeat: Include a minimally reproducible example in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Аnd wish you good luck in finding the answer to your question.

as @AnyDozer. The first parameter in the request.security() function is a symbol You can't use var float real_atm

I can use simple int or simple string, but when I am concatenating with current price of the symbol, it is throwing error

Either closing from the candle or from any source I want the symbol price just once from the opening
